# Group Similar in Chrome Console is not working

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I have a list of React components and I log the same message each time a component is (re-)rendered. In the past, when I've had similar situations, Chrome console would group these messages. This time around, the grouping feature is not working and I can't figure out why. Any help would be appreciated.

**UPDATE:** By coincidence, I realized the issue occurs specifically while the dev tools window is open. I was running some tests without the dev tools window open and when I opened the window, the logs were grouped. Here is an updated log window, containing messages logged while the dev tools window was open, followed by messages logged while the dev tools window was closed.

Example log:

[image: Log Messages]

Console settings:

[image: Console settings]

Comment: Sounds like a bug in devtools.

Comment: I should mention, I occasionally noticed some XMLHttpRequest logs for 3rd party getting grouped.

Comment: Is it possible you have other logs occurring between those logs, but they are simply getting filtered out due to your console filter levels?  It's possible that the grouping considers _all_ messages to the console, not only those which are displayed at the current filter levels.

Comment: @AlexanderNied That was a good suggestion, however it didn't turn out to be the case. I retried using all levels and messages were still not grouped. While trying that though, I stumbled upon another hint as indicated in the updated question.